# How to select pet name in drop down from sales customer form in Odoov10

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, odoo, odoo-10, many-to-one

I inherite(res.partner) sales customer form. And make changes with adding some addition fields. Now when call this form another place in Many2one type then only customer name shown in drop down. How to show pet name in drop-down?

My code is here:

**Python Code:**

```
class customer_information(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    pet_name = fields.Char("Pet Name")
    dog_cat = fields.Selection([('dog', 'Dog'), ('cat', 'Cat')], string="Dog/Cat")
    species = fields.Many2one('species.pet', string="Species")
    pet_size = fields.Selection([('large', 'Large'), ('medium', 'Medium'), ('small', 'Small')], string="Size")
```

**Module Where i want pet name:**

```
class machine_weight(models.Model):
    _name = 'machine.weight'

    machine_id = fields.Many2one('sale.pet', string='Machine Weight', ondelete='cascade', index=True,
                                 copy=False)

    pet = fields.Many2one('res.partner.pet_name')
    weight = fields.Integer()
    price = fields.Integer()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use name_get methode :

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for record in self:
        name = record.name
        if record.pet_name :
            name = '[' + record.pet_name + ']' + ' ' + record.name
        result.append((record.id, name))
    return result
```

Comment: Can u explain me, how complete this function for pet_name field from 'res.partner" form?

Comment: My function is not working after For Loop(for record in self:), I call this function in field like that:
pet = fields.Many2one('res.partner', change_default=True, default=name_get)

Comment: You don't call this function, this function use to change the name of record,

Comment: and for more info search in google `odoo name_get methode`

Comment: Ok, But i getting following for this function. How to solve it?
"(name = record.pet_name + ' ' + record.name
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str')".

Comment: `if record.pet_name :`

Comment: Hello Anonymouse,

Now, My function work well. But, Can u tell me how to call this function for particular class only, not global. My class name is "body_processing" where i want to call this 'name_get' function. My code is here:

@api.multi

def name_get(self):

result = []

for record in self:

name = '['

if record.pet_name:

name += record.pet_name + ']' + ' ' + record.name

else:

name += '] ' + record.name

result.append((record.id, name))

return result

Comment: I think this need more documentation

Answer (score 1):

This function give solution for problem. So, problem solved

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for record in self:
        name = '['
        if record.pet_name:
            name += record.pet_name + ']' + ' ' + record.name
        else:
            name += '] ' + record.name
        result.append((record.id, name))
    return result
```